# debian create tasksel for installing docker

Tags: debian

On debian 11. I create descs file to install docker. Before this I create docker repo and gpg so when I install the from command  apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io it works but when I trying to install with tasksel it does not install anything the tasksel is:

```
Section: laptop
Description: Install docker
  Install docker
key:
Packages: list
 docker-ce
 docker-ce-cli
 containerd.io
```

and when i run dry # `tasksel -t install` i get:

```
dockerdebconf-apt-progress -- apt-get -q -y -o APT::Install-Recommends=true -o APT::Get::AutomaticRemove=true -o Acquire::Retries=3 install docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-ce
What I missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error message, `tasksel -t` display the way how the list of package will be installed.

Create a `mytask.desc` under `/usr/share/tasksel/descs` (`laptop` task already exist use a different task name):

```
Task: mytask
Section: user
Description: Install docker
  Install docker
Key:
Packages: list
  docker-ce
  docker-ce-cli
  containerd.io
```

tasksel doesn't install anything because the package is already installed.

Remove the installed package:

```
sudo apt remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Then:

```
sudo tasksel install mytask
```